# PhantomJS includeJs() + Nested evaluate() Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs

Consider the following code...

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
console.log('The default user agent is ' + page.settings.userAgent);
page.settings.userAgent = 'Lisas headless browser';
page.open('http://www.httpuseragent.org', function(status) {
    if (status !== 'success')
    {
        console.log('Unable to access network or site is down');
    }else{
        page.includeJs(
            // Include the https version, you can change this to http if you like.
            'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js',
            function() {
                (page.evaluate(function() {
                    // jQuery is loaded, now manipulate the DOM
                    console.log(document.getElementById('myagent').textContent);
                }))
            }
        );
    }
    phantom.exit();
});
```

I'm trying to get some code going that inserts jquery and then allows me to continue performing actions but it doesn't evaluate includeJs()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** As mentioned by Vaviloff in the comment below, you need to subscribe to 'page.onConsoleMessage' events in order to use console.log() inside the page.evaluate() callback. I've updated the code block below to reflect this.

The following code will capture the user agent text from the page using jQuery and also capture evidence of the page content having been manipulated.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
console.log('The default user agent is ' + page.settings.userAgent);
page.settings.userAgent = 'Lisas headless browser';
// simple 'page.onConsoleMessage' event handler
page.onConsoleMessage = function (msg) {
  console.log('page.onConsoleMessage');
  console.log(msg);
};
page.open('http://www.httpuseragent.org', function(status) {
  if (status === 'success') {
    // capture the rendered page to 'before.jpg'
    page.render('before.jpg');
    // load the jQuery library
    page.includeJs(
      'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js',
      function() {
        // jQuery is loaded, now manipulate the DOM
        var agent = page.evaluate(function() {
          // This code is executed within the loaded page
          // get the user agent string
          var text = $('#myagent').text();
          // log the text to the console
          console.log('Inside page.evaluate ::', text);
          // time for some mischief
          $('#myagent').html('PhantomJS Strikes Again!');
          // return the text string
          return text;
        });
        // capture the evidence
        page.render('after.jpg');
        // print the user agent text
        console.log(agent);
        // exit now
        phantom.exit(0);
      });
  } else {
    console.log('Unable to access network or site is down');
    phantom.exit(1);
  }
});
```

Resulting console output:

```
The default user agent is Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/538.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) PhantomJS/2.1.1 Safari/538.1
page.onConsoleMessage
Inside page.evaluate :: Your Http User Agent string is: Lisas headless browser
Your Http User Agent string is: Lisas headless browser
```

Comment: Well, actually he can use console.log inside of page.evaluate. Just need to subscribe to messages from console with [page.onConsoleMessage](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-console-message.html).